# Exception in Delegate CustomClass UIView

Tags: swift

I am trying to delegate a function with which I will call the new ViewController. In run, it gets this error:

```
setValue: forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mapView. '
```

What am I doing wrong or how can I fix it? I will be grateful for all the tips.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

ViewController.swift:
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nib = UINib(nibName:"Maps", bundle:nil)
        let MapsView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! Maps
        MapsView.delegate = self
}

func showWaypointDetails() {
        print("show")
}

Maps.swift:
protocol CustomViewDelegate: class {
    func showWaypointDetails()
}

class GpsMaps: UIView, MKMapViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    weak var delegate: CustomViewDelegate?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are either not instantiating the right view or the view is not set up correctly.

In your Maps.xib file:

1. Check if the "File's Owner" points to your Maps.swift class
2. Check if you have a MKMapView outlet named "mapView"

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the nib (which I assume contains a MKMapView) as Maps, which is just a simple protocol. In doing this you will lose all mapView functionality as the app won't know it's a MapView.

You need to load it and cast it as the MapView Class you are using, and then adopt the protocol in your MapView class...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nib = UINib(nibName:"Maps", bundle:nil)
        let mapsView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! MyMapViewClass
        mapsView.delegate = self
}

extension MyMapViewClass: Maps {
 // implement showWaypointDetails()  or implement it as a default in a protocol extenstion
}
```